# HTML5 Canvas blending & IE / Edge

Tags: internet-explorer, canvas, microsoft-edge

I'm working on a project that makes use of Canvas blending - of course, IE/Edge still don't support blending modes. Some simplified code ([fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/78xwp8c3/5/)) that shows the issue:

```
<canvas id="below" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
<canvas id="texture" width="100" height="100"></canvas> 
<canvas id="composite" width="100" height="100" style="z-index:1x solid green;"></canvas>

var can = document.getElementById('below');
var below = can.getContext('2d');
below.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
below.fillRect(0,0,512,512);
var can2 = document.getElementById('texture');
var texture = can2.getContext('2d');

var img = new Image;
img.onload = function(){
    texture.drawImage(img,0,0);
    var can3 = document.getElementById('composite');
    var composite = can3.getContext('2d');
    composite.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
    composite.drawImage(can, 0, 0);
    composite.drawImage(can2, 0, 0);
};
img.src = "http://i.imgur.com/DGuWpEg.png";
```

I came across [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158696/blend-modemultiply-in-internet-explorer) which seems to have a workaround, but I'm not quite sure how to properly implement it.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stackoverflow member and contributor Phrogz has published a very nice library that uses `context.getImageData` to fetch + blend the pixel data from an image and then uses `context.putImageData` to apply blending to the image.

His library supports these compositing, coloring & blending modes:

- src-over
- screen
- multiply
- difference
- src-in
- plus
- add
- overlay
- hardlight
- colordodge
- dodge
- colorburn
- burn
- darken
- darker
- lighten
- lighter
- exclusion
- softlight
- luminosity
- color
- hue
- saturation
- lightercolor
- darkercolor

**Phrogz's Blending library is available on GitHub:**

https://github.com/Phrogz/context-blender

**And since it's liberally licensed, below is a copy for Stackoverflow posterity:**

Context Blender JavaScript Library

Copyright © 2010 Gavin Kistner

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
THE SOFTWARE.

```
(function(){

var defaultOffsets = {
  destX   : 0,
  destY   : 0,
  sourceX : 0,
  sourceY : 0,
  width   : 'auto',
  height  : 'auto'
};

if (typeof require==='function' && typeof module==='object'){
  var canvas = require('canvas');
  addBlendMethod(canvas.Context2d.prototype);
  module.exports = canvas;
} else addBlendMethod(this.CanvasRenderingContext2D && this.CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype);

function addBlendMethod(object){
  if (!object || typeof object.getImageData!=='function') return console.error("context blender called without a valid context prototype");
  Object.defineProperty(object,'blendOnto',{value:blendOnto});

  // For querying of functionality from other libraries
  var modes = blendOnto.supportedBlendModes = 'normal src-over screen multiply difference src-in plus add overlay hardlight colordodge dodge colorburn burn darken darker lighten lighter exclusion softlight luminosity color hue saturation lightercolor darkercolor'.split(' ');
  var supports = blendOnto.supports = {};
  for (var i=modes.length;i--;) supports[modes[i]] = true;
  blendOnto.aliases = { "src-over":"normal", plus:"add", dodge:"colordodge", burn:"colorburn", darker:"darken", lighter:"lighten" };
  return object;
}

function blendOnto(destContext,blendMode,offsetOptions){
    var offsets={};
    for (var key in defaultOffsets){
      if (defaultOffsets.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        offsets[key] = (offsetOptions && offsetOptions[key]) || defaultOffsets[key];
      }
    }
    if (offsets.width =='auto') offsets.width =this.canvas.width;
    if (offsets.height=='auto') offsets.height=this.canvas.height;
    offsets.width  = Math.min(offsets.width, this.canvas.width-offsets.sourceX, destContext.canvas.width-offsets.destX );
    offsets.height = Math.min(offsets.height,this.canvas.height-offsets.sourceY,destContext.canvas.height-offsets.destY);

    var srcD = this.getImageData(offsets.sourceX,offsets.sourceY,offsets.width,offsets.height);
    var dstD = destContext.getImageData(offsets.destX,offsets.destY,offsets.width,offsets.height);
    var src  = srcD.data;
    var dst  = dstD.data;
    var sA, dA, len=dst.length;
    var sRA, sGA, sBA, dRA, dGA, dBA, dA2,
        r1,g1,b1, r2,g2,b2;
    var demultiply;

    function Fsoftlight(a,b) {
      /*
        http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Soft_Light
        2ab+a^2 (1-2b), if b<0.5
        2a(1-b) +sqrt(a)(2b-1), otherwise
      */
      var b2=b<<1;
      if (b<128) return (a*(b2+(a*(255-b2)>>8)))>>8;
      else       return (a*(511-b2)+(Math.sqrt(a<<8)*(b2-255)))>>8;
    }

    function Foverlay(a,b) {
      return a<128 ?
        (a*b)>>7 : // (2*a*b)>>8 :
        255 - (( (255 - b) * (255 - a))>>7);
    }

    function Fdodge(a,b) {
      return (b==255 && a==0) ? 255 : Math.min(255,(a<<8)/(255-b));
    }

    function Fburn(a,b) {
      return (b==255 && a==0) ? 0 : 255-Math.min(255,((255-a)<<8)/b);
    }


    /*
      // yyy = similar to YCbCr
      0.2990    0.5870    0.1140
      -0.1687   -0.3313    0.5000
      0.5000   -0.4187   -0.0813
    */
    function rgb2YCbCr(r,g,b) {
      return {
        r: 0.2990*r+0.5870*g+0.1140*b,
        g: -0.1687*r-0.3313*g+0.5000*b,
        b: 0.5000*r-0.4187*g-0.0813*b };
    }

    /*
      1.0000   -0.0000    1.4020
      1.0000   -0.3441   -0.7141
      1.0000    1.7720    0.0000
    */
    function YCbCr2rgb(r,g,b) {
      return {
        r: r +1.4020*b,
        g: r-0.3441*g   -0.7141*b,
        b: r+1.7720*g };
    }

    function rgb2hsv(r,g,b) {
      var c=rgb2YCbCr(r,g,b);
      var s=Math.sqrt(c.g*c.g+c.b*c.b),
          h=Math.atan2(c.g,c.b);
      return {h:h, s:s, v:c.r };
    }

    function hsv2rgb(h,s,v) {
      var g=s*Math.sin(h),
          b=s*Math.cos(h);
      return YCbCr2rgb(v,g,b);
    }


    for (var px=0;px<len;px+=4){
      sA  = src[px+3]/255;
      dA  = dst[px+3]/255;
      dA2 = (sA + dA - sA*dA);
      dst[px+3] = dA2*255;

      r1=dst[px], g1=dst[px+1], b1=dst[px+2];
      r2=src[px], g2=src[px+1], b2=src[px+2];

      sRA = r2/255*sA;
      dRA = r1/255*dA;
      sGA = g2/255*sA;
      dGA = g1/255*dA;
      sBA = b2/255*sA;
      dBA = b1/255*dA;

      demultiply = 255 / dA2;

      var f1=dA*sA, f2=dA-f1, f3=sA-f1;

      switch(blendMode){
        // ******* Very close match to Photoshop
        case 'normal':
        case 'src-over':
          dst[px  ] = (sRA + dRA - dRA*sA) * demultiply;
          dst[px+1] = (sGA + dGA - dGA*sA) * demultiply;
          dst[px+2] = (sBA + dBA - dBA*sA) * demultiply;
        break;

        case 'screen':
          dst[px  ] = (sRA + dRA - sRA*dRA) * demultiply;
          dst[px+1] = (sGA + dGA - sGA*dGA) * demultiply;
          dst[px+2] = (sBA + dBA - sBA*dBA) * demultiply;
        break;

        case 'multiply':
          dst[px  ] = (sRA*dRA + sRA*(1-dA) + dRA*(1-sA)) * demultiply;
          dst[px+1] = (sGA*dGA + sGA*(1-dA) + dGA*(1-sA)) * demultiply;
          dst[px+2] = (sBA*dBA + sBA*(1-dA) + dBA*(1-sA)) * demultiply;
        break;

        case 'difference':
          dst[px  ] = (sRA + dRA - 2 * Math.min( sRA*dA, dRA*sA )) * demultiply;
          dst[px+1] = (sGA + dGA - 2 * Math.min( sGA*dA, dGA*sA )) * demultiply;
          dst[px+2] = (sBA + dBA - 2 * Math.min( sBA*dA, dBA*sA )) * demultiply;
        break;

        // ******* Slightly different from Photoshop, where alpha is concerned
        case 'src-in':
          dA2 = sA*dA;
          demultiply = 255 / dA2;
          dst[px  ] = sRA*dA * demultiply;
          dst[px+1] = sGA*dA * demultiply;
          dst[px+2] = sBA*dA * demultiply;
          dst[px+3] = dA2*255;
        break;

        case 'plus':
        case 'add':
          // Photoshop doesn't simply add the alpha channels; this might be correct wrt SVG 1.2
          dst[px  ] = Math.min(sRA + dRA,1) * demultiply;
          dst[px+1] = Math.min(sGA + dGA,1) * demultiply;
          dst[px+2] = Math.min(sBA + dBA,1) * demultiply;
        break;

        case 'overlay':
          dst[px]   = f1*Foverlay(r1,r2) + f2*r1 + f3*r2;
          dst[px+1] = f1*Foverlay(g1,g2) + f2*g1 + f3*g2;
          dst[px+2] = f1*Foverlay(b1,b2) + f2*b1 + f3*b2;
        break;

        case 'hardlight': // hardlight(a,b) = overlay(b,a)
          dst[px]   = f1*Foverlay(r2,r1) + f2*r1 + f3*r2;
          dst[px+1] = f1*Foverlay(g2,g1) + f2*g1 + f3*g2;
          dst[px+2] = f1*Foverlay(b2,b1) + f2*b1 + f3*b2;
        break;

        case 'colordodge':
        case 'dodge':
          dst[px]   = f1*Fdodge(r1,r2) + f2*r1 + f3*r2;
          dst[px+1] = f1*Fdodge(g1,g2) + f2*g1 + f3*g2;
          dst[px+2] = f1*Fdodge(b1,b2) + f2*b1 + f3*b2;
        break;

        case 'colorburn':
        case 'burn':
          dst[px]   = f1*Fburn(r1,r2) + f2*r1 + f3*r2;
          dst[px+1] = f1*Fburn(g1,g2) + f2*g1 + f3*g2;
          dst[px+2] = f1*Fburn(b1,b2) + f2*b1 + f3*b2;
        break;

        case 'darken':
        case 'darker':
          dst[px]   = f1*(r1<r2 ? r1 : r2) + f2*r1 + f3*r2;
          dst[px+1] = f1*(g1<g2 ? g1 : g2) + f2*g1 + f3*g2;
          dst[px+2] = f1*(b1<b2 ? b1 : b2) + f2*b1 + f3*b2;
        break;

        case 'lighten':
        case 'lighter':
          dst[px  ] = (sRA<dRA ? dRA : sRA) * demultiply;
          dst[px+1] = (sGA<dGA ? dGA : sGA) * demultiply;
          dst[px+2] = (sBA<dBA ? dBA : sBA) * demultiply;
        break;

        case 'exclusion':
          dst[px  ] = (dRA+sRA - 2*dRA*sRA) * demultiply;
          dst[px+1] = (dGA+sGA - 2*dGA*sGA) * demultiply;
          dst[px+2] = (dBA+sBA - 2*dBA*sBA) * demultiply;
        break;

        case 'softlight':
          dst[px]   = f1*Fsoftlight(r1,r2) + f2*r1 + f3*r2;
          dst[px+1] = f1*Fsoftlight(g1,g2) + f2*g1 + f3*g2;
          dst[px+2] = f1*Fsoftlight(b1,b2) + f2*b1 + f3*b2;
        break;

        case 'luminosity':
          var hsl  = rgb2YCbCr(r1,g1,b1);
          var hsl2 = rgb2YCbCr(r2,g2,b2);
          var rgb=YCbCr2rgb(hsl2.r, hsl.g, hsl.b);
          dst[px]   = f1*rgb.r + f2*r1 + f3*r2;
          dst[px+1] = f1*rgb.g + f2*g1 + f3*g2;
          dst[px+2] = f1*rgb.b + f2*b1 + f3*b2;
        break;

        case 'color':
          var hsl  = rgb2YCbCr(r1,g1,b1);
          var hsl2 = rgb2YCbCr(r2,g2,b2);
          var rgb=YCbCr2rgb(hsl.r, hsl2.g, hsl2.b);
          dst[px]   = f1*rgb.r + f2*r1 + f3*r2;
          dst[px+1] = f1*rgb.g + f2*g1 + f3*g2;
          dst[px+2] = f1*rgb.b + f2*b1 + f3*b2;
        break;

        case 'hue':
          var hsl =rgb2hsv(r1,g1,b1);
          var hsl2=rgb2hsv(r2,g2,b2);
          var rgb=hsv2rgb(hsl2.h, hsl.s, hsl.v);
          dst[px]   = f1*rgb.r + f2*r1 + f3*r2;
          dst[px+1] = f1*rgb.g + f2*g1 + f3*g2;
          dst[px+2] = f1*rgb.b + f2*b1 + f3*b2;
        break;

        case 'saturation':
          var hsl =rgb2hsv(r1,g1,b1);
          var hsl2=rgb2hsv(r2,g2,b2);
          var rgb=hsv2rgb(hsl.h, hsl2.s, hsl.v);
          dst[px]   = f1*rgb.r + f2*r1 + f3*r2;
          dst[px+1] = f1*rgb.g + f2*g1 + f3*g2;
          dst[px+2] = f1*rgb.b + f2*b1 + f3*b2;
        break;

        case 'lightercolor':
          var rgb = 2.623*(r1-r2)+5.15*(g1-g2)+b1-b2>0 ? {r:r1,g:g1,b:b1} : {r:r2,g:g2,b:b2};
          dst[px]   = f1*rgb.r + f2*r1 + f3*r2;
          dst[px+1] = f1*rgb.g + f2*g1 + f3*g2;
          dst[px+2] = f1*rgb.b + f2*b1 + f3*b2;
        break;

        case 'darkercolor':
          var rgb = 2.623*(r1-r2)+5.15*(g1-g2)+b1-b2<0 ? {r:r1,g:g1,b:b1} : {r:r2,g:g2,b:b2};
          dst[px]   = f1*rgb.r + f2*r1 + f3*r2;
          dst[px+1] = f1*rgb.g + f2*g1 + f3*g2;
          dst[px+2] = f1*rgb.b + f2*b1 + f3*b2;
        break;

        default: // ******* UNSUPPORTED mode, produces yellow/magenta checkerboard
          var col = (px/4) % this.canvas.width,
              row = Math.floor((px/4) / this.canvas.width),
              odd = (col%8<4 && row%8<4) || (col%8>3 && row%8>3);
          dst[px] = dst[px+3] = 255;
          dst[px+1] = odd ? 255 : 0;
          dst[px+2] = odd ? 0 : 255;
      }
    }
    destContext.putImageData(dstD,offsets.destX,offsets.destY);
}

})();
```